# Bash - Appending values to variable

Tags: bash, variables

I am still snooping around bash as a newbie and I wanted to ask some question
Is it possible to append additional text to value in bash?
Example below:

```
#!/bin/bash
value1="qwerty"
value2="asdfgh"

echo $value1 >> $value3
echo $value2 >> $value3
echo $value3
```

So my question is - can I create value that contain other values?
Why am I trying to do this? Because I want to do some logical functions for each value and if it meets the criteria it gets appended to my final value.
By the end I would echo value3 and it would contain all results that met criteria.

Comment: `value3=${value1}; value3+=${value2}`

Comment: `$value3` is, specifically, the *value* of the variable, not the variable itself. If `>>` *did* work with variables, you would write something like `echo "$value1" >> value3` (But in reality, this just appends the contents of `value1` to a file named `value3`.)

Answer (score 0):

`>>` is for writing to files, not appending to variables. You just want string interpolation.

```
value3="$value1$value2"
```

If you want an embedded newline, you can do that:

```
value3="$value1
$value2"
```

If you want to append a value to an *existing* variable,

```
value3=$value1

value3="$value3
$value2"
```

Comment: Thank you! But returned value displays then in one row. Can I enter carriage returns?

Comment: And also it will add value1 to value3 even if it will not meet the criteria.

Comment: What criteria? You never mentioned anything about that in your question.